# WPF DataTrigger on TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, datatrigger, tabitem

I have the following UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfExample.Views.TabsUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:v="clr-namespace:WpfExample.Views"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfExample.ViewModels"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"

             DataContext="{Binding TabsViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabViewModel}">

        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewDatabaseTableViewModel}">
                <v:ViewDatabaseTableUserControl />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
                <v:CustomerView />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SystemSetupViewModel}">
                <v:SystemSetupUserControl />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="120" />
                <!--<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.ProductIsLicensed}" />
                    <Trigger Property="{Binding Header}" Value="System Setup">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>-->
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    </TabControl>    
</UserControl>
```

I would like to use a DataTrigger to enable/disable tabs based on wheter or not the product is licensed.  I thought this might work (added within the `<TabControl>` block):

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.ProductIsLicensed}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

But it gives me an exception of "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll".

Can someone tell me how to accomplish the disabling of tabs if the `ProductIsLicensed` value is False?

Comment: Did you put the ControlTemplate inside a style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for triggers or ControlTemplate, this will just ruin all the default stylings. Just create a style and bind the IsEnabled directly

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Path="{Binding IsProductLicensed}"/>
</Style>
```

By not supplying a key to the style, it will apply to all TabItems in the user control.

A ControlTemplate defines all the look and feel of the control, and can only be applied to the Template property inside a style. It should only be used if you want to completely style a control from scratch. This is how it would look

```
<Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                <!-- Define ALL here - look, effects, triggers etc. -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```